# How to convert String to List<int> in Dart?

Tags: dart

`String data= '[1, 2, 3]';`

i want to convert my string to `List<int>`

expectations: `[1, 2, 3]`

what i got using my code:

`print(json.decode(data));`

result: `1`

dataType: `int`

Comment: try this List<int>.from(json.decode(data).map((x) => x));

Comment: The given code gives your expected value already.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this,

```
import 'dart:convert';

var list = json.decode(data);
```